# Is there a way to make GDB print something to tell me that a line has been executed, without stopping?

Tags: c++, multithreading, gdb

I'm debugging multi-threaded code and I would just like to know if a line has been reached without it stopping but I don't want to start adding print statements everywhere.

Is this possible? Thanks!

Comment: How about a ["code coverage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_coverage)" tool. Such a tools helps you determine which lines of your code have been executed. It may also have "term coverage" which will help you know which parts of boolean expressions have been executed. See also ["Open Source C Code Coverage Tool with Gui"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458186/open-source-c-code-coverage-tool-with-gui)

Comment: How about `printf("I got here"); fflush(NULL);`.  Works a treat here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can attach commands to a breakpoint in gdb with the 'commands' command. One of those commands can be 'continue'.

Answer (score 3):

You may be looking for tracepoints.  These capture variable values without stopping execution.

- http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Tracepoints.html